# Multithreading vector multiplication

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, radix

Suppose we have a system with radix 2^32 (x = a0 * 2^0 + a1 * 2^32 + a2 * 2^64 +...) and we store the coefficients in a vector (a0 in position [0] , a1 in position [1] ...).

This function allows you to calculate the square of x (for simplicity the non-zero coefficients of x occupy only half of the vector).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

const int64_t esp_base_N = 32; 
const uint64_t base_N = 1ull << esp_base_N;

void sqr_base_N(std::vector<uint64_t> &X, std::vector<uint64_t> &Sqr , const int64_t len_base_N)
{
    std::vector<uint64_t> Sqr_t(len_base_N, 0ull);
    uint64_t base_N_m1 = base_N - 1ull;
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < (len_base_N / 2); i++)
    {
        uint64_t x_t = X[i];
        for (int64_t j = i + 1; j < (len_base_N / 2); j++)
        {
            uint64_t xy_t = x_t * X[j];
            Sqr_t[i + j] += 2ull * (xy_t & base_N_m1);
            Sqr_t[i + j + 1] += 2ull * (xy_t >> esp_base_N);
        }
        x_t *= x_t;
        Sqr_t[2 * i] += x_t & base_N_m1;
        Sqr_t[2 * i + 1] += x_t >> esp_base_N;
    }

    uint64_t mul_t;
    mul_t = Sqr_t[0] >> esp_base_N;
    Sqr[0] = Sqr_t[0] & base_N_m1;
    for (int64_t j = 1; j < len_base_N  ; j++)
    {
        Sqr[j] = (Sqr_t[j] + mul_t) & base_N_m1;
        mul_t = (Sqr_t[j] + mul_t) >> esp_base_N;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is possible to speed up the function using multithreading.

I tried using OpenMP but managed to get no error just by applying to the outer for loop, furthermore the function is slower than the previous one.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int64_t i = 0; i < (len_base_N / 2); i++)
{
    uint64_t x_t = X[i];
    x_t *= x_t;
    Sqr_t[2 * i] += x_t & base_N_m1;
    Sqr_t[2 * i + 1] += x_t >> esp_base_N;
}
for (int64_t i = 0; i < (len_base_N / 2); i++)
{
    uint64_t x_t = X[i];
    for (int64_t j = i + 1; j < (len_base_N / 2); j++)
    {
        uint64_t xy_t = x_t * X[j];
        Sqr_t[i + j] += 2ull * (xy_t & base_N_m1);
        Sqr_t[i + j + 1] += 2ull * (xy_t >> esp_base_N);
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to use multithreading for the function (OpenMP or other) to speed it up?

Edit (to test the function):

```
int main()
{ 
    int64_t len_base_N = 6;
    std::vector<uint64_t> X_t(len_base_N, 0ull);
    X_t[0] = 1286608618ull;
    X_t[1] = 2;
    std::vector<uint64_t> Sqr_X(len_base_N, 0ull);
    sqr_base_N(X_t, Sqr_X , len_base_N);
    for(int64_t i = 0; i < len_base_N - 1; i++)
        std::cout << Sqr_X[i] << ", ";
    std::cout << Sqr_X[len_base_N - 1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any C++ code concerning the performance of the code should be accompanied by the compiler and compiler options used to build the application.  The most important of these options are the *optimization levels*.  You need to specify the optimization level used when you built the application.

Comment: Probably this question about code performance should belong to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Not sure about OpenMP but why not use 3D math libraries which does that for you? They will use SIMD instruction set, so it will be a lot faster.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie For example compile using the -fopenmp -O3 option if your using GCC. The problem is that I couldn't get it to work by leaving the internal for loop.

Comment: @Asesh I just wanted to test something simple created by me without the need to use libraries.

Comment: @Asesh  compilers are smarter than that... they can recognize matrix multiplication loops and emit the SIMD code even from normal C++ code (if CPU's support SIMD instructions ofcourse).  See : https://godbolt.org/z/j45a3Pf45

Comment: @PepijnKramer hmm it's been ages, I have not done 3D programming. Back then we had to. So I wasn't aware of it. Thanks

Comment: @Asesh *I just wanted to test something simple created by me without the need to use libraries.* -- I see this mentioned so many times in a lot of questions here.  If you know that there are libraries that do what you are trying to do, but at the same time do not want to use those libraries, then why not see how those libraries work?  If the library has source code, why not study it to see the "tricks" that they are using to get their library to work correctly?  Doesn't that make more sense, in terms of time and learning, to see how the "professionals" do things?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because they are too complex and I can't understand how they all work.

Comment: Did you consider that maybe the complexity is there because the task at hand is not trivial?

Comment: @Asesh -- Sorry, the comment was meant for the OP.

Comment: I have run a quick test and with your function, the result I get for `9876543210^2 = (2*2^32 + 1286608618)` is `385418938*2^32 + 1942818276` when it should have been `97546105778997104100 = 5*2^64 + 1236886114*2^32 + 1942818276`. I do not think I am doing anything wrong though (please provide example of how I should have called your function if I am); perhaps you should correct your function before trying to optimize it. BTW, I believe the correct way to optimizing it is to implement e.g. Karatsuba multiplication, no? Always better to use a faster algorithm than several cores.

Comment: Bonus, Karatsuba, Toom-Cook, Schonage-Strassen algorithm all being divide-and-conquer algorithms, they are better candidates to be run on separate threads: split your operand, calculates the bits in the separate threads, join the threads and merge the result.

Comment: @Atmo I think it's due to the fact that you entered the wrong vector length. I edited it by adding the main to test the function.

Comment: @user140242: With the example you have given, I get an *vector subscript out of range* error, apparently caused by adding `2` in the expression `int64_t len_base_N = 2 * X_t.size() + 2;`. That is another reason for me to say this function is not clean enough yet. I do not really get why your function requires a length parmeter to be aware of the length of the vector: the size of `X` is `X.size()` and the size of `Sqr` must be at most `2 * X.size()` for the result to be stored. That should be enough, no?

Comment: @Atmo Sorry, I corrected it.

Comment: I see. The issue was apparently that I was passing a length of 3 when I tried your function when it in facts expects 4 for some reason (leaving a leading 0 in the vector). Anyway, that brings us to the next comment I have made above: multithreading has a very slow start and is only faster for the biggest numbers. Have you had a look at Karatsuba as an alternative? You can have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) or [some documentation](https://github.com/AtmoFX/bigint/blob/master/documentation/multiplication.md) I wrote recently

Comment: @PepijnKramer You example mismatch with your explanation. It shows that the compiler propagate constants and is able to pre-compute the output. There is no computing SIMD instructions in the compiled result, just movs. If `m1` and `m2` are passed in parameters, you can see that the compiler do *not* actually use SIMD instructions (and is rather inefficient by the way).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Oops me bad... I stand corrected.

Comment: @Charley Not really. This question is fine here with additional profiling informations so to make it more reproducible (since the OP only focus about speed and not a general review). See [Performance question - Stack Overflow or Code Review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review)